# Showing data after making a post request without refreshing the page in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am making a post request to create notes. After the success callback, I am pushing the new data into scope of the notes. But the page isn't showing the updated array of notes.
My code is as follows:

Controller.js

```
    var populateNotes = function (err) {
                $scope.notes = [];
                if (err) {
                    return err;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < NotesService.getNotes()
                    .length; i++) {
                    $scope.notes.push({
                        text: NotesService.getNotes()[i].note,
                        when: $moment(NotesService.getNotes()[
                            i].ct)
                            .fromNow()
                    })
                };
                console.log("notes: ", $scope.notes);
            }

    $scope.createNote = function () {
                var data = {
                    note: $scope.notetext
                };
                model.createNote(id, aid, data, populateNotes);
            }
```

And my html is as follows:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="note in notes">
         <td class="text-center">{{note.text}}</td>
         <td class="text-center">{{note.when}}</td>
    </tr>
```

The problem is that on creating the post request successfully, the dom should update and show the newly created note automatically. But this is not happening. Can anybody let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Angular will update the view just after an event (click, focus, ...) happened. In your case, the post response happens after the rendering, resulting in an outdated view. You need to tell it to apply changes:

```
var populateNotes = function (err) {
    ...
    console.log("notes: ", $scope.notes);
    $scope.$apply('notes');
}
```

Comment: Hi, I used $apply but it is showing me this error:
 
err : $digest already in progress